# Upload using python script takes very long on one laptop as compared to another

Tags: python, upload, ftp

I have a python 2.7 code which uses STORBINARY function for uploading files to an ftp server and RETRBINARY for downloading from this server.

However, the issue is the upload is taking a very long time on three laptops from different brands as compared to a Dell laptop. The strange part is when I manually upload any file, it takes the same time on all the systems.

The manual upload rate and upload rate with the python script is the same on the Dell Laptop. However, on every other brand of laptop (I have tried with IBM, Toshiba, Fujitsu-Siemens) the python script has a very low upload rate than the manual attempt. Also, on all these other laptops, the upload rate using the python script is the same (1Mbit/s) while the manual upload rate is approx. 8 Mbit/s.

I have tried to vary the filesize for the upload to no avail. TCP Optimizer improved the download rate on all the systems but had no effect on the upload rate. Download rate using this script on all the systems is fine and same as the manual download rate.

I have checked the server and it has more than 90% free space. The network connection is the same for all the laptops, and I try uploading only with one laptop at a time. All the laptops have almost the same system configurations, same operating system and approximately the same free drive space. If anything the Dell laptop is a little less in terms of processing power and RAM than 2 of the others, but I suppose this has no effect as I have checked many times to see how much was the CPU usage and network usage during these uploads and downloads, and I am sure that no other virus or program has been eating up my bandwidth.

---

even with 'storbinary' command , when i specify the blocksize to be of 57344(56 kB), the upload rate improves to about 5 Kbit/s from 1 to 1.5 Kbit/s originally...whats the reason for that? and how can i find out the blocksize used by my manual upload client(i used filezilla), or better yet the optimal blocksize for upload?? @guidot

---

Complete code :

```
def upnew(counter=0):

    f=open("c:/10", "w")

    f.write(os.urandom(10*1024*1024))
    f.close()

    print "Logging in..."

    ftpserver='xxxxxxx'

    ftpuser='xxxxxxx'

    ftppw='xxxxxxxxx'

    ftp = FTP(ftpserver)    
    ftp.login(ftpuser, ftppw)  

    t = open("c:/10", "rb")                       
    upstart = time.clock() 

    ftp.storbinary('STOR 10', t)

    upende = time.clock()-upstart

    print ((10*8)/upende)

    print "press Return to disconnect"
    raw_input()

    ftp.quit()
    print "FTP Verbindung abgebaut"


upnew(1)
```

Comment: The laptops are all running windows? Can you share the code that does the upload?

Comment: Have you isolated any processing that is going on? A simple "upload generic text file" function without any data handling or other processing would help you isolate where the problem is coming from.

Comment: A bit off-topic for S/O as it's not really specifically a programming related problem (except Python happens to be used for FTP it's more system/network/setup related) - maybe superuser/admin with all the gory system details would stand a better chance of a gaining a useful answer.

Comment: Assuming your ftp parameter is the FTP module: try to find out, which block size the manual transfer method uses and pass this as 3rd parameter to storbinary to ensure you are doing the transfer the same way.

Comment: You could watch what's happening with wireshark - the packet timestamps might give a clue as to where the delays are.  It sounds like you've done all the right things to narrow down the problem - good luck finding it.

Comment: I experienced simillar behavior but with http requests. It turned out to be difference in time machine was resolving the host from dns server.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a working sample of your code... without being able to see how your implementing the ftp function its impossible to give useful feedback, but in general you might benefit from using threads or sockets.

Comment: the code has been added in the original question...can you check it out guys...thanks

@Meikel Deitrick

Comment: Check out my earlier post on a related project... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844608/valueerror-in-thread-callback-function-trying-to-update-ftp-progress

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it appears that the issue resides in the way you call and use ftp.storbinary()

I would try using ftp.ntransfercmd() instead and use a buffer to breakup the transfer as it processes. This gives you the added benefit of being able to track to the progress of ftp transfer and in theory allow you to pause and restart the process as needed.

Haven't tested the performance of this script but you could try doing something like this:

```
    def ftpUploader():
        BLOCKSIZE = 57344 # size 56 kB

        ftp = ftplib.FTP()
        ftp.connect(host)
        ftp.login(login, passwd)
        ftp.voidcmd("TYPE I")
        f = open(zipname, 'rb')
        datasock, esize = ftp.ntransfercmd(
            'STOR %s' % os.path.basename(zipname))
        size = os.stat(zipname)[6]
        bytes_so_far = 0
        print 'started'
        while 1:
            buf = f.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            if not buf:
                break
            datasock.sendall(buf)
            bytes_so_far += len(buf)
            print "\rSent %d of %d bytes %.1f%%\r" % (
                  bytes_so_far, size, 100 * bytes_so_far / size)
            sys.stdout.flush()

        datasock.close()
        f.close()
        ftp.voidresp()
        ftp.quit()
        print 'Complete...'
```

Comment: even with 'storbinary' command , when i specify the blocksize to be of 57344(56 kB), the upload rate improves to about 5 Kbit/s from 1 to 1.5 Kbit/s originally...whats the reason for that?

and how can i find out the blocksize used by my manual upload client(i used filezilla), or better yet the optimal blocksize for upload??

@guidot

Answer (score 0):

Python is primarily used for scripting and process automation and is not technically considered a vary fast language (though faster than most other scripting languages). Filezilla is coded using C/C++ and is far superior to Python in performance. That being said, its not a fair comparison and we should consider it when trying to identify issues in logic that may cause general performance issues.

storbinary basically acts as a wrapper for ntransfercmd, calling ntransfercmd without requiring us to define our own buffer (hence the reason for my earlier recommendation).

Additionally, after analyzing your code snip-it again, I noticed that your calling storbinary via the print statement... is this in error?

At this point, we'll need all of the related code used in this example to identify any issues in logic that may affect performance, please build upon your previous snip-it to provide us with additional information.

Another factor to consider here is the general system environment in which your conducting your tests... consider the location of each system you've preformed said testing on, how far away they are from the FTP server, additionally, differences in ISP or DNS servers could play a major factor when troubleshooting performance issues related to TCP/IP based connections such as ftp.

Comment: If you've tried all this and your still not happy with the responsiveness of your application then the next step would be to brake up the process (using the ntransfercmd or transfercmd functions) with the use of sockets... in theory, you could transfer several blocks at the same time if you use a socket to connect to the ftp server. However, this is an advanced topic that I'm under qualified to handle. If you plan on going this route I'd recommend starting an new thread/question.

Comment: sorry for the late reply and thanks for your continuing help Meikel...the print statement doesn't make a difference, the results are same with or without it... the difference in performance between C and python could have been an issue if the result was the same on all the systems i tested on... all the systems were tested in the same environment, at exactly the same distance and with the same connection to the internet...however on the Dell laptop, the uploadrate from this python code is the same as the Filezilla client manual upload, while on all the other systems , these uploadrates go down

Comment: I have tested various part of the code separately and i am sure that the problem arises because of this STORBINARY. One of these other laptops has almost the same configurations and settings as that of the DELL Laptop, same RAM, free memory , cache  and the operating system. The Dell Laptop has the Broadcom NetXtreme 57xx Gigabit Controller while the other system has the Boradcom NetXtreme Gigabit Controller, but i doubt this would have much effect on uploading a 10 MByte file . Also the manual uploadrate is the same on both. The problem is with this upload using STORBINARY.

Comment: I will try with the 'ntransfercmd' and let you know the results. Meanwhile can you let me know what kind of difference in ISP can cause upload performace issues for the Python code..(as i am pretty sure that the issue here is with the code and not the computer's performance capabilites)

Comment: So..i checked with the ntransfercmd function as well. Exactly the same uploadrates as were with STORBINARY. It appears that with both the 'storbinary' and the 'ntransfercmd', the uploadrate differs upon changing the blocksize. The blocksize between 54 Mbyte and 84 Mbyte giving the best uploadrates (still a little less than the manual upload)

Comment: To your question about ISPs... there are many reasons an ISP might be suspect (though if I'm guessing right, this may not apply in this case) ISPs use throutling to maint integraty and often employ strick rules about bandwidth usage, not all ISPs are considered equal and while you or your friends may be connected via the same general providers you could be connecting via completely different hosts. When troubleshooting TCP/IP you have to consider the distance or number of hops from the server you're trying to contact. Its not uncommon from an ISP to reroute traffic to different locations...

Comment: Its possible, though unlikely, that the ISP could be routing traffic for one system (assuming they are all on the same network or are connecting via a shared/common internet connection) differently or along another path as compared to the other systems. It could even have to do with the DNS server used to contact/identify the ftp server (again assuming the ftp server is not local to your internal network). If communicating with an external ftp server, try setting a simple ftp server on your internal network and see if you still have the same issue. Simply everything...

Comment: Testing the connectivity and speeds of your internal network might help you rule out a lot of third party issues. Also, it would be a good idea to disable any security software (anti-virus, anti-malware, firewall, etc.) and verify the settings of your router as well. If on one system the script runs well, then logic would suggest that maybe the issue is not in the script itself but with the enviornment in which it is run. The question being... whats different between these systems??